# How do you move a ResultSet cursor to a specific row?

Tags: java, resultset

I want to be able to find and display data from any input column, I don't know how to move the cursor to the right row however.

This is my code, I know the getRow line is wrong.

```
ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
int colIndex;
int rowIndex;
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select COMPANY_CD from ARCUS where CUSTOMER_NO = '"+customer+"'");
rowIndex = rs.getRow();
rs.absolute(rowIndex);
colIndex = rs.findColumn("COMPANY_CD");
System.out.println(colIndex);
rowPane.add(new JLabel(metadata.getColumnName(colIndex)));
rowPane.add(new JLabel(rs.getObject(colIndex).toString()));
```

Comment: Use `rs.next()`, to advance the cursor by one position

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I need to know how to move the cursor to a specific row based on one columns field

Comment: Why do you need the cursor? It is usually of no use outside your block of code. You get the row number when you've iterated over it and you can store the row (or just it's row number) in a variable.

Comment: Because I need to print a value from a specific row, and I need the cursor to be on that row.

Comment: Read the Oracle Tutorials. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Answer (score 1):

You can go forward or backward or to before last or before first

```
//Move cursor forward
while (resultSet.next()) {
  // Get data at cursor
  String s = resultSet.getString(1);
}

// Move cursor backward
while (resultSet.previous()) {
  // Get data at cursor
  String s = resultSet.getString(1);
}

// Move cursor before first record
resultSet.beforeFirst();
```

Comment: I tried to loop through the data and stop once it gets to the right row, but this code gives me a "Column not found" error:

rs=stmt.executeQuery("select COMPANY_CD from ARCUS where CUSTOMER_NO = '"+customer+"'");
        while (rs.next())
        {
         if (rs.getRowId("CUSTOMER_NO").toString() == customer)
          break;
        }
        colIndex = rs.findColumn("COMPANY_CD");
        System.out.println(colIndex);
        rowPane.add(new JLabel(metadata.getColumnName(colIndex)));
        rowPane.add(new JLabel(rs.getObject(colIndex).toString()));

Comment: because in your select there's no column named "CUSTOMER_NO". When getting by column names, make sure you use names that would be available in the select  ( hence  in the resultSet )

Comment: I changed it to "select *" but now i get a SQLFeatureNotSupportedException error

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to solve a similar problem:

rs.absolute(integer) will move the cursor to the row number specified by the integer

rs.relative(integer) will move the cursor relative to the current position by integer

The sample below will pull 6 blocks of 10 rows each from the result set.

Be sure to specify that the cursor is SCROLL_INSENSITVE

Good luck

```
PreparedStatement pstmt;
pstmt = myConn.prepareStatement("Select * from log limit 55", 
ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { // Pull 6 blocks
    rs.absolute(i * 10);
    counter = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
       received = rs.getString("log_received");
       callsign = rs.getString("log_callsign");
       duration = rs.getString("log_duration");
       line = String.format("%3d %3d %15s     %-8S    %5s",i, counter, received, callsign, duration);
       System.out.println(line);
       counter++;
       if (counter >= 10) { // Limit to 10 rows
           break;
       }
     }
```

// Do some other stuff and get the next block

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over your result to get your target row, then end the loop

```
 int rowIndex;
 while (yourResultSet.next()) {

     if(checkRowIsValid(yourResultSet)){
     rowIndex = yourResultSet.getRow(); 
     break;
     }

 }
```